# Why I can't exstends controller from My controller on Codeigniter.2.2.1?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create some controller and call it from **library** and library will exstends from **Core**
Here is 
**my  Controller**

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Page extends Frontend_Controller {

            public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
            }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('main/main_index');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**And Here is Frontend_Controller in lirbray**

```
 class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller{

                public function __construct() {
                    parent::__construct();
                }
     }
```

**Here is MY_Controller in Core**

```
 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

                    public function __construct() {
                        parent::__construct();
                    }
         }
```

But I got this errors

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controllers' not found in D:\My data\project\wamp\www\Ecom\application\controllers\page.php on line 3
```

It is errors in **Codeigniter2.2.1**
Notes: It is work perfect on **Codeigniter2.2.0**

Comment: Because you are trying to extend  Class 'MY_Controllers, and your controller is not  'MY_Controllers it's My_Controller, see it?

Comment: Oh I write wrong in this pages but it my project is corrent

Comment: Whats on page.php line 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frontend_Controller should not be a library. You need to put this in your application's core folder along with my_controller and then add an autoloader to my_controller.

Add this autoloader to the end of my_controller.php:

```
/**
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Native Autoload - by Phil Sturgeon. New Version!
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Nothing to do with config/autoload.php, this allows PHP autoload to work
 * for base controllers.
 */
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include_once $file;
        }
    }
}


/* End of file MY_Controller.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Controller.php */
```

Comment: It is different from old version right. because when I used this code it will work with old version

Comment: But now when I changes Core to library it will work if I put my frontend_Controller in library

Comment: 2.2.1 is only a minor update so it does not introduce any framework-breaking changes. If your code works in 2.2.0 then it should work in 2.2.1 as far as I can tell. When you upgraded to 2.2.1, did you make sure to carry over any system-level changes? You can read the full changelog **[here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html)**

Comment: Yes but it is different from change __autoload from Config to My_Controller

Comment: when i refresh my pages

Page rendered in 0.4372 seconds

Comment: There can be many reasons for that. Which part took the longest?